# Online forms (or other workaround) with spreadsheet/database, autocomplete, autofill & triggered actions

Tags: database, forms, google-sheets, spreadsheet, online-forms

The reason for my question is to see if you can give me an idea (similar or not) or know of any type of software/web app available for the following that I am going to tell you.

**The context**

My sister works in the healthcare industry and currently manually handles several different spreadsheets (Google sheets) in a way for her customers and incomes.

**My idea**

He had thought of an online form for income. This form would have, among others, a field for the customer's name that would be automatically filled in from the customer's spreadsheet as it is searched while typing. If it exists, other fields on the form will also be filled in automatically. If it doesn't exist, once the revenue-related data is populated and submitted, a trigger would update the new customer data in the customers spreadsheet so that the next time the form is used, the field customer name can be auto-completed with the updated customers.

**My solution**

I have tried a lot of online forms and softwares: J*otform, Caspio, Logiforms, Typeform, Gravity Forms, Formsite, Quinta DB, Airtable, Rest.io, Ninox, Podio, Cognito Forms, Matrify, Zoho* ... but without full success.

For this purpose, the only ones that fit us are JotForm (it would be semi automatic since it does not automatically link spreadsheets), Caspio (it is perfect but excessively expensive for us, € 200, since the basic plan does not include triggers), Logiforms ( its trial is very limited and we cannot test if it would really work for us)

I tell you all this to ask for your help and to ask you if you know of any other software, web app, solution or even think of another different workaround to forms that I have not thought of and can help us.

Thank you very much for everything and a hug.

Comment: In your situation, how about using [Google Form](https://www.google.com/intl/en/forms/about/) or [custom HTML form created by Google Apps Script, Javascript and HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)? When the custom HTML form is used, I think that it has higher flexibility than Google Form. You can also see sample situations and scripts in Stackoverflow. But it seems that these are not included in `My solution`. So if these were not the direction you expect, I apologize. By the way, do you suppose how many users the form will be used?

Comment: Not sure if "what tool for my job" type of question is accepted on StackOverflow. You should probably look at asking this question into the "nocode" community as they are really experts into connecting things together. It will probably be hard to find a solution that does all that. You probably need to build some "glue" code in between.